# How to translate ImageMagick commands into ImageMagick API calls?

Tags: imagemagick

I need to do some light image processing on large image, and I try to use ImageMagick for that. Unfortunately, the API documentation has a very low information content, with documentation similar to:

```
MagickDeleteImageArtifact

MagickDeleteImageArtifact() deletes a wand artifact.

The format of the MagickDeleteImageArtifact method is:

MagickBooleanType MagickDeleteImageArtifact(MagickWand *wand, const char *artifact)

A description of each parameter follows:

image
  the image.

artifact
  the image artifact.
```

Could anybody suggest a few information sources for ImageMagick that would have, you know, information?

(and yes, this piece of "documentation" is pasted from ImageMagick web site, with the incorrect parameter)

**Edit**: Here is the context: I develop an iOS application, so I want to call ImageMagick from the C language (or Objective-C or C++). The need is to split large images that would not fit in the limited amount of RAM of an iOS device into smaller "tiles" (and downsample for lower resolution versions too. But once I have the tiles, I can do that using only iOS facilities).

**Edit 2**: Using the command line, I can achieve this tiling with the "convert" command with corresponding parameters. So my immediate need would be to translate such a command line command into the relevant set of API calls.

Comment: Are you using ImageMagick from the command line or one of its APIs? And what are you actually trying to do? Unless there is comprehensive and readable documentation somewhere (there isn't, I don't think), this question is currently sort of unanswerable in its generality.

Comment: OK, I'll add more info to my question. But clearly, I mention the API, so the assumption that this question is *not* about the command line would be correct :-)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I have a similar problem.